# How do I hide or show layout elements when an Android Activity goes out of focus?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to hide certain elements in a layout when Android goes out of focus, such that when viewed in the "View recent applications" display, the layout elements will not be visible. Upon selecting the application and going into focus, these elements will be visible again.

My implementation below attempts to show the "content" layout when the application is in focus, and show the "overlay" layout when out of focus, via onWindowFocusChanged().

**activity_main.xml**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="This is the content page"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/overlay"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="This is the overlay"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    FrameLayout layoutContainer;
    RelativeLayout layoutContent;
    RelativeLayout layoutOverlay;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        layoutContainer = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.container);
        layoutContent = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.content);
        layoutOverlay = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.overlay);

    }

    @Override
    public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {

        if (hasFocus) {
            layoutContent.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            layoutOverlay.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else {
            layoutOverlay.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            layoutContent.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

    }
}
enter code here
```

However, my implementation does not work. Anyone with any suggestion as to solve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hide views in your layout in recent apps try like this

```
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);
```

Comment: I tried your solution and it works, but it prevents users from taking screenshots. Is there an alternative solution that allows screenshots as well? Thanks.